# How to load the component in ReactJs dynamic?

Tags: reactjs

We are developing web application using visual studio framework, Our project have numbers of component.But the Issue is that for every component we are referring that in index.html page,because of this our index page's size is increasing.Some of the component referring I am showing below.

```
<script src="Scripts/CommentList.jsx"></script>
<script src="Scripts/CommentForm.jsx"></script>
<script src="Scripts/CommentBox.jsx"></script>
<script src="Scripts/app.jsx"></script>
```

Now how can i solve this performance issue, Is there any other way that I can load this component dynamically, One solution I think can be if I am referring one component inside other component based on requirement.What is the best way to solve this issue?

Comment: You can use **code splitting** with webpack

Comment: @Hosar can you elaborate?